# Trouble running newest kernel (grub not recognizing kernel)

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, kernel, raid

I was having some boot issues, after finding some workarounds I was able to boot again with the linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic kernel. The issue is that I have other kernels now, linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic, that are not being picked up by grub. Nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Here is the info dump from boot-repair:

http://paste2.org/YdHIb9PB

I am not sure if this is also related but after these boot issues I have had a huge cut in performance on some of the workloads on my system. Any advice would be great.